# Under what circumstances might bluebird's "Possibly unhandled Error" warning be wrong?

Tags: javascript, bluebird

The word "possibly" suggests there are some circumstances where you can get this warning in the console even if you catch the error yourself.

What are those circumstances?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is pretty well [explained in the docs](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#error-handling):

> Unhandled rejections/exceptions don't really have a good agreed-on
>   asynchronous correspondence. The problem is that it is impossible to
>   predict the future and know if a rejected promise will eventually be
>   handled.
>
> The [approach that bluebird takes to solve this problem], is to call a
>   registered handler if a rejection is unhandled by the start of a
>   second turn. The default handler is to write the stack trace to
>   `stderr` or `console.error` in browsers. This is close to what happens
>   with synchronous code - your code doesn't work as expected and you
>   open console and see a stack trace. Nice.
>
> Of course this is not perfect, if your code for some reason needs to
>   swoop in and attach error handler to some promise after the promise
>   has been hanging around a while then you will see annoying messages.

So, for example, this might warn of an unhandled error even though it will get handled pretty well:

```
var prom = Promise.reject("error");
setTimeout(function() {
    prom.catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err, "got handled");
    });
}, 500);
```

Comment: From what I've seen with bluebird this warning will also be happening if you have an .error() handler in your code but the actual error is not of type Error. E.g. return(Promise.reject('Unhandled')) will do this while return(Promise.reject(new Error('Unhandled'))) won't. Apart from Error also other types seem to be working in that fashion, though not Strings.

Comment: @andig `.error` is not an alias to `.catch`, it only catches operational errors so other kind of errors will pass through and if you don't have handler for those then it will report it as possibly unhandled